# Tricky Data manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset on which I would like to perform the following transformation:
For each ID in `x_1`, change the largest negative number (closest to zero) under `z_1` into zero. Leave other negative or positive numbers as they are. If there is no negative number or if there is a zero, do nothing.

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1","A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "B500", "C100", "C100", "C100", "D40", "G100", "G100")

z_1 <- c(1.1, 1.4, 1.6, -1.0, -2.2, 3, 2.3, 2.0, -3.4, -4.1, 2, 2, 2.4, -3.5)

A <- data.frame(x_1, z_1)
```

Desired result:

```
x_1   z_1
A1    1.1
A1    1.4
A1    1.6
B10  -2.2
B10   0
B10   2.3
B10   3.0
B500  2.0
C100 -4.1
C100  0
C100  2.0
D40   2.0
G100  0
G100  2.4
```

I've tried a few things using dplyr but I don't seem to be getting the right result.

```
A3 <- A %>%group_by(x_1, z_1)%>% summarize(neg = max(z_1 < 0))
```

Clearly, this code is incomplete but I would really appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to produce the result you desire

```
A %>% group_by(x_1) %>% 
    mutate(z_1=ifelse(z_1==max(c(-Inf,z_1[z_1<0])), 0,z_1)) %>% 
    arrange(x_1, z_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(A)[, .I[z_1== max(c(-Inf, z_1[z_1 <0]))],,x_1]$V1
A[i1, z_1:= 0.0][order(x_1, z_1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!